# How to view class test coverage line by line?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-studio-3.5

I am trying to see test coverage line by line in a class, however, only the first line is highlighted.

[image]

The *Show Inline Statistics* setting is enabled.

[image]

I get the test coverage for the **class**, **methods** and **lines** as below:

[image]

I remember this worked in a previous version of Android Studio (ca't exactly remember which). How can enable the feature so that coverage is shown for all lines.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1 - 
Run **testDebugUnitTest** with coverage 
[Click here to see unit test coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy5oF.png)

Step 2 - 
Generate coverage report - click on icon as shown in above image (yellow highlighted) give exported path to generate html file.

Step 3 - Click on index.html file to view report.

You will get test coverage percentage for **class, method and line** as shown in below image 
 [Click here to see test coverage class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guNFM.png)

[click here to see overall coverage summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWvoT.png)

Answer (score -1):

Run the test with coverage, then you can see it line by line:

[image]

Comment: I have done that. I get the coverage, but when I click on the class it only shows [the image I added in my description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdlna.png). That is the only line highlighted in the whole class.

Comment: Didn't enable it in `build.gradle` with `testCoverageEnabled true`?

Comment: I am using the Intellij IDEA runner instead of Jacoco. I get the test coverage but only one of the lines in the class is highlighted, when 82% of them should be. I have edited my question to share the test coverage.